# Display inline cause error in code behind

Tags: css, asp.net, .net, vb.net

this is my following code:

```
<tr id="trPrice" style = "display:none;">
     <td colspan=2></td>
     <td><b>Price:</b></td>
     <td><asp:textbox id="txtPrice" runat="server" style = "border-style:none"></asp:textbox></td> 
</tr>
```

And in my Code behind I want to set the style of the trPrice to "display:inline" at a specific page_load ->

```
Protected WithEvents txtPrice As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox

' In Page_Load function:
If type = 3 Or type = 4 Then
        trPrice.Attributes.Add("style", "display:inline")
End If
```

But this error occurs:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You need `runat="server"` to make this `tr` available for code-behind

Comment: its a spelling mistake, try txtPrice.Attributes instead :-)

Comment: @Andrei thanks! what a stupid mistake :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make it `runat="server"`, then visual studio will add this to the designer.vb file:

```
Protected WithEvents trPrice As Global.System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow
```

and it will be initialized in `Page_Load`.